# Error when submit topology in Nimbus

Tags: apache-storm, apache-zookeeper

The error i had when submit a topology

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at backtype.storm.utils.NimbusClient.<init>(NimbusClient.java:36)
at backtype.storm.utils.NimbusClient.getConfiguredClient(NimbusClient.java:17)
```

This what i got in nimbus log file

```
2015-09-22 04:19:58 ClientCnxn [INFO] Socket connection established to   
localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, initiating session
2015-09-22 04:20:13 ConnectionState [ERROR] Connection timed out
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: 
KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss
at com.netflix.curator.ConnectionState.getZooKeeper(ConnectionState.java:72)
at com.netflix.curator.CuratorZookeeperClient.getZooKeeper(CuratorZookeeperClient.java:74)
```

and here my storm.yaml file

```
storm.zookeeper.servers:
  - "127.0.0.1" 
nimbus.host: "127.0.0.1"
storm.local.dir: /tmp/storm
drpc.servers:
  - "127.0.0.1"
  - "server2"
```

is there anything else ??! what's wrong i have here ?

Comment: is zookeeper running ? are you submitting this to cluster ?

Comment: yes i ran zookeeper i found the solution for half hour ! the problem was in the size of nimbus i updated it and ran successfully but i have now problem in zookeeper Unable to reconnect to ZooKeeper service, session 0x14ff864dff70000 has expired, closing socket connection ,is there any problem if the connection closed or it should be open all the time and how can i do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the size of nimbus 
it should be greater as possible

like

```
nimbus.thrift.max_buffer_size: 20480000
```